# Setting the value of a dropdown list when a page loads

Tags: drop-down-menu, onload, selectedvalue

Hi and thanks for your help,

I am trying to set the value of a dropdown box when my page loads.
Right now it gives me no errors, but the dang dropdown box isn't set to the value I wanted.

Here is my code:

```
<body onLoad="IssuesToReportForm.ReportTo.SelectedValue = '<%=strReportTo%>'">
```

Is this part of the code my problem?

Thanks,
Will

Comment: SelectedValue is a .NET thing...  using javascript, you can only set selectedIndex.  Maybe some more details?

Comment: I believe that looping through the elements with the function I provided will do the trick, haven't tried it though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function PreselectMyItem(itemToSelect)
  {

    // Get a reference to the drop-down
    var myDropdownList = document.IssuesToReportForm.ReportTo;

    // Loop through all the items
    for (iLoop = 0; iLoop< myDropdownList.options.length; iLoop++)
    {    
      if (myDropdownList.options[iLoop].value == itemToSelect)
      {
        // Item is found. Set its selected property, and exit the loop
        myDropdownList.options[iLoop].selected = true;
        break;
      }
    }

  }
</script>
```

Assuming `IssuesToReportForm` is your form name and your `ReportTo` dropdown's name.

Then `<body onLoad="PreselectMyItem('<%=strReportTo%>')">`

[Source](http://imar.spaanjaars.com/QuickDocId.aspx?quickdoc=292)